# Apache Pig: FLATTEN (udf generated) bag followed by join causes ClassCastException

Tags: python, apache-pig

I'm trying to flatten a bag of values to multiple records in Pig and then join these records with other records with these flattened values.
However, my effort keeps resulting in a ClassCastException (Pig DataByteArray to Java Integer). Here's a MWE to reproduce this problem.

**Input files**

File a: `a.txt`

```
123, fruit1
234, fruit2
345, fruit3
783, fruit4
928, fruit5
317, fruit6
937, fruit7
```

File b: `b.txt`

```
global23; [num1#123,num2#234]
global45; [num1#783,num2#928,num3#317]
```

Python UDF: `udf.py`

```
@outputSchema("values:bag{t:tuple(value:int)}")
def bag_of_tuples(map_dict):
    return map_dict.values()
```

Pig script:

```
REGISTER 'udf.py' using jython as udf;

a = LOAD 'a.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (num: int, fruit: chararray);
b = LOAD 'b.txt' using PigStorage(';') AS (global: chararray, mymap: map[]);
c = FOREACH b GENERATE global AS (global: chararray), FLATTEN(udf.bag_of_tuples(mymap)) AS (othernum: int);

d = JOIN a BY num, c BY othernum;
DUMP d;
```

**Expected result**

Joined records, e.g.:

```
num, fruit, global, othernum
(123, fruit1, global23, 123)
(234, fruit2, global23, 234)
...
```

Any ideas? This [might be a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3938).